# Problem with import JSON in Firefox but in other browsers it work

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

In my new Project I have a problem with Firefox. Firstly I want to say in Opera, Chrome and Edge it works good but only in that one browser is unexpected error.

I am using local JSON with some objects, then in JS I am using

```
// Import JSON Insurance Data

import insurances from './insurances.json' assert {type: 'json'}
```

then

```
insurances.forEach(e => {myCode});
```

Like I told it normally works but in Firefox in the console is that error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
```

The browser points to to this line:

```
import insurances from './insurances.json' assert {type: 'json'}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just by looking at MDN docs, Firefox doesn't support import assertions.

I am also confused how come it is working in Opera for you since at the moment it is listed as unsupported, same as Firefox.

See more here: [MDN import browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue as the OP. Import assertions was working well in Chrome, but it did not work in Firefox. I got the following error message when trying to import a file and asserting its type as `json`:

> import assertions are not currently supported.

Subsequently, I found this [article](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/how-do-i-import-data-from-json-to-javascript/526050) that suggested to read the imported file using `fetch` inside of an asynchronous method instead. This worked for me.

Here, you can view the browser support for `fetch`: [MDN Fetch browser compatability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)